# Why is my Firebase console going insane after installing CLI twice?

Tags: javascript, firebase-cli

I installed Firebase CLI twice and this happened:

[image]

Why did it happen? And why does [Carl Pilcher](https://astrobiology.nasa.gov/nai/directory/pilcher-carl/index.html) show among the gibberish (gibberish to me might be some cool code)?

EDIT: It was ASCII ART, here's the image.

[image]
[image]

But I still need to solve the issue.

I downloaded the Firebase CLI Binary for Windows and have an error

```
events.js:292
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: spawn C:\Users\Usuario\DOWNLO~1\FIREBA~1.EXE ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn C:\\Users\\Usuario\\DOWNLO~1\\FIREBA~1.EXE',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Usuario\\DOWNLO~1\\FIREBA~1.EXE',
  spawnargs: [ '--tool:setup-check' ]
}
```

[image]

FINAL EDIT: After reopening the Binary Firebase CLI it worked! Thank you for the help

Carl ASCII Art Characters

!             H|H|H|H|H           H__________________________________             H|§|§|§|H           H|* * * * * *|---------------------|             H|§|∞|§|H           H| * * * * * |---------------------|             H|§|§|§|H           H|* * * * * *|---------------------|             H|H|H|H|H           H| * * * * * |---------------------|             H|H|H|H|H           H|---------------------------------|          ===============        H|---------------------------------|            /| _   _ |          H|---------------------------------|            (| O   O |)          H|---------------------------------|            /|   U   |          H-----------------------------------             |  =/  |           H              *...*/            H              *|I/|*            H      *******/| H |/*******    H     /           / /          H    |          | | /         |  H    |          ||o||          |  H    |    |     ||o||     |    |  H    |    |     ||o||     |    |  H   Carl Pilcher

Comment: This is due to an _unfortunate_ update in `colors.js` ~ https://github.com/Marak/colors.js/commit/074a0f8ed0c31c35d13d28632bd8a049ff136fb6

Comment: Relevant firebase-tools issue here ~ https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3999

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for now I've solved it by downloading Firebase CLI binary for Windows from
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli

Comment: Hi I tried this but got an error, by any chance do you know how to solve it?

Comment: It worked thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

While I won’t project on “what happened” or how to solve it, the “cool code” shown appears to be [ASCII Art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art).

If narrowing the terminal to 80 columns, an image should appear. (I’m a bit curious as to what.)

Note the repetitions `H|…|H` on the first lines that would stack vertically if wrapped. 80 is the ‘traditional’ column count on a terminal which, at quick glance, appears to be the period of the repetitions.

—

Following the link in a the [issue reporter](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3999) (provided by Phil in acomment) leads to [Dev corrupts NPM libs 'colors' and 'faker' breaking thousands of apps](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/dev-corrupts-npm-libs-colors-and-faker-breaking-thousands-of-apps/):

> Initially, users suspected that the libraries 'colors' and 'faker' used by these projects were compromised [but] it was the dev behind colors and faker who appears to have intentionally committed the code responsible [when the developer] *added a "new American flag module"* to colors.js library yesterday in version v1.4.44-liberty-2 ..

Here is the [commit on Github](https://github.com/Marak/colors.js/commit/074a0f8ed0c31c35d13d28632bd8a049ff136fb6) where the “new flag” can be clearly seen in the source. (I am unsure where the remaining gibberish comes from exactly; perhaps that is a downstream error artifact.)

It appears the fix is then to avoid the problematic dependency versions.

Comment: I got curious too, I edited the question and added the image. I am wondering tho if Carl did it. Anyway thanks

Comment: Cool! Try with 79 columns. I think the flag should hang straight down and the area underneath is the moon. That would fit with Pilcher’s career. Although I’m not sure it’s his work per se .. could be though as three is no reason why it had to be created recently.

Comment: I uploaded one with the flag straight, put copy-pasted the characters because the console keeps running non-stop. I got it after asking if Carl he did it, the picture is his. In the picture, his face is kind of sideways so I'll add the characters in another edit in case you want to paste them in the console and try to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has to do with the dependencies used that were corrupted. https://github.com/Marak/colors.js/issues/285